# Find the biggest index in extension of file in a bash script

Tags: bash, sh

So I have a folder with bunch of files.
File, File.0, File.1, File.2

I'm trying to find the biggest `index` in extension of this files. So it has to be 2.

I wrote this command, which count all files with `numeric extension`.
But it's not working properly when the index is greater than 10. It's not working at all, because **I just want to find biggest index, not sum of file with number in index.**

```
$1 (is file name in this case File)

y=$(echo $(ls -d $1.[0-inf] | wc -l))
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What happens when your argument `$1` is `File.1` ? Do you want to search for files named `Files.1.0`, `Files.1.1`, `Files.1.2` and so on ?

Comment: Yes. Index means value after last dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First tip : [do not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Especially in your case.

You could use the following script in pure bash to address your issue :

```
#!/bin/bash

# needed for correct glob expansion
shopt -s nullglob

# we check every file following the format $1.extension
max_index=0
for f in $1.*
do
    # we retrieve the last extension
    ext=${f##*.}
    re="^[0-9]+$"

    # if ext is a number and greater than our max, we store it
    if [[ $ext =~ $re && $ext -gt $max_index ]]
    then
        max_index=$ext
    fi
done
echo $max_index
```

Comment: What about this ?                                  `y=$(echo $(ls -d $1.*[0-9]* | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'))

max=0
for v in $y; do
    if [ $v -gt $max ]; then
     max=$v
     fi
done`

Comment: @davoid when the file is not present : `ls: cannot access 'nothing.*[0-9]*': No such file or directory`. This is why you don't use `ls` in those cases

Comment: Ok. Thank you for this information. But i presume that the file exist.

Comment: @davoid Also, if you have files like so :  `"file.0", "file.0.0", "file.0.1"` and test your script with `$1 == "file.0"`, it will return `max == "01"` instead of `max == 1`

Comment: @davoid yeah but the problem is when you have `text.0.0`, `text.0.1`, `text.0.2` and use `text.0` as your search file

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Thank you. It's not that easy as it looked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for i in file\.*; do echo ${i##*.}; done | sort -g | tail -n1
```

`${i##*.}` is removing everything before the last `.` in the filename.

`sort -g` is sorting as numeric value.

`tail -n1` prints the last index.

A more error prone way is to use `find`command as the it will cope with file not matching the pattern, filename with spaces...

```
find -type f -name "file\.*" -exec bash -c 'echo ${1/*\.}' _ "{}" \; 2>/dev/null | sort -n | tail -n1
```

`bash -c 'echo ${1/*\.}' _ "{}"` is the command that will strip the characters before the `.`.

You may want to add `-maxdepth 1` at the beginning of the command to avoid looking recursively inside directories.

Comment: if there are no files following the naming pattern, your script will return a list of all the files of the current directory